# Unable to Receive Replies with Discord Slash Commands and Interactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently experiencing an issue with Discord slash commands and interactions. Specifically, I am unable to receive any replies when using these features. I have been attempting to create a Discord bot command that can take information from replies, but I have not been successful in getting it to work.

I have tried multiple solutions even tried generating code with AI but that didn't work either. Below is the command base I am using maybe that is the issue, could anyone help with this issue? The command base works fine for anything else but when I try working with replies it just decides to not work.

```
@bot.tree.command(name='upload', description='Uploads a file.')
async def upload(interaction: discord.Interaction):
```

I have tried generating the code for me with AI but still didn't solve my issue. When I tried with ctx everything worked fine but then the command didn't show up below other bot commands like image below.
[Image of other commands appearing fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJe5l.png)

Comment: You need to [sync your commands](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f#file-02-in_depth_syncing-md) with discord.

Comment: Already done below is the code for it:
`@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(msuccess + 'Bot started successfully!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="/commands"))
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'Synced {len(synced)} command(s)')
    except Exception:
        print(mfailure + 'Something went wrong!')
        print(Exception)`

Comment: You often also need to restart your discord app, so the commands appear for you to use.

Comment: Yeah but this isn't the issue I am looking to fix. I am looking for code to take data from the reply that the user who executed the command replied with to the bot's message. Or another way to get the attachment from a slash command.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the attachment as an argument to your command:

```py
from discord import app_commands


@bot.tree.command(name='upload', description='Uploads a file.')
@app_commands.describe(attachment='provide the file you want upload')
async def upload(interaction: discord.Interaction, attachment: discord.Attachement):
    pass
```

Comment: Would this also be usable in my case? Because u cannot add attachments to a slash command.

Comment: Why you cannot add attachments to slash commands? The command will request a file to be upload.

Comment: Tysm I didn't know the attachment argument was a thing I thought I had to make some weird reply system for it. You honestly saved me so much time.